# Show div on image hover Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've spent a good 30 minutes on S.O to find a solution but still can't find it. Probably due to the fact that I don't know exactly what to look for.

Basically I have div which contains and image and a text. The text should appear on the image only after I hover on the image. The HTML and CSS structures are all good and I'm having problem with the JQuery on `hover` function, mainly to know how to select the inner div (and not actually how to use the `hover` function itself).

What I'm trying to do is when I hover on an image div (`img-container`), it shows the text (`hover-img`) on that image.

Below are my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="content" class="col-12">
  <!-- Image Gallery -->
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12 img-container">
    <img class="img-gal" src="#" />


    <div class="hover-img">
      <p class="img-text">Text on Hover</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div
```

**CSS**

```
.img-container{
  float:left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.img-gal{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.hover-img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:10;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

.img-text{
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

**JS**

```
//Hover Image. Need to show the Text when hovering on an image
$('.img-container').hover(function(){
  //Stuck here. How to show the text? fadeIn()? But what?
},function(){
  //Stuck here. How to show the text? fadeOut()? But what ?
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with pure CSS:

```css
.hover-img {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.img-gal:hover ~ .hover-img, .hover-img:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="col-12">
  <!-- Image Gallery -->
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12 img-container">
    <img class="img-gal" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0104050baad43a135d1084a1b3ec35d4?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />


    <div class="hover-img">
      <p class="img-text">Text on Hover</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div
```

Comment: This pure css works, but the text keeps flashing like crazy on the hover.

Comment: What do you mean, "flashing like crazy"? Seems to appear when you mouseover the image, and disappear when you mouseout.

Comment: I mean that, when I use your CSS here, it works in principle, the text shows up. But it flickers very fast as if it's flashing. I'm not sure how to explain it. The text does not stay still but it keeps blinking fast. I don't know if this might be to the absolute position or something?

Comment: Is the `.hover-img` appearing directly over the image? If so, if the mouse happens to be over the `.hover-img`  when the `.img-gal`'s `:hover` is triggered, the `display: block` rule will stop applying - until the text disappears and the `.hover-img` starts being hovered over again. You could add a rule to have `.hover-img` keep displaying if it's being hovered over. See edit

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying. `.hover-img` appears directly over the image. I understand now that this is why it's flickering. Your edit works perfect! Thanks. Just want to know how does that `~` thing in CSS work? What is it called? Never saw this before

Comment: It's the general sibling combinator https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

Answer (score 1):

You do this only with CSS. Add this line to your css

```
.img-gal:hover + .hover-img {
    display:block;
}
```

if you want to smooth effect add this line to .hover-img. and remove `display:none`

```
  .hover-img {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
```

and on image hover like this

```
.img-gal:hover + .hover-img {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Works way better with the transition but still kind of flashes on mouse out. Also it doesn't work perfectly while I change divs, not sure why.

Comment: Now I am on mobile so I am not able test properly. I give you demo after some time.

Comment: CertainPerformance found the solution first. I'm giving you an upvote because your solution works and I'll apply your transition technique to the answer above. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It&#39;s ok @nTuply. I am just here to help you. Not for  upvote:)

Answer (score 1):

As other mentioned, no need for jQuery here,
you can achieve this with html/css only, using css transition and by changing the opacity and position of the text layer.

https://jsfiddle.net/86bjzedh/

check this fiddle for a working example

CSS:

```
.gallery li {
  overflow: hidden;  
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.gallery span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: .3s linear all;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: tahoma;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  padding-top: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery li:hover span {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="gallery">
  <li style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/17/10/22/key-3087900__180.jpg)">
    <span>Style 1</span>
  </li>
    <li style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/16/02/03/pocket-watch-3156771__180.jpg">
    <span>Style 2</span>
  </li>
      <li style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/20/02/47/hong-kong-3334945__180.jpg)">
    <span>Style 2</span>
  </li>
<li style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/17/10/22/key-3087900__180.jpg)">
    <span>Style 1</span>
  </li>
    <li style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/16/02/03/pocket-watch-3156771__180.jpg">
    <span>Style 2</span>
  </li>
      <li style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/20/02/47/hong-kong-3334945__180.jpg)">
    <span>Style 2</span>
  </li>  
</ul>
```